# Dependency present in Effective POM but not in Dependency tree

Tags: java, maven

I have a Dependency(which contains the package a.b.c) present in `Effective POM` but while building the project I am getting error that `package a.b.c does not exist`

Also that Dependency is **not** present in the dependency tree

**EDIT :
Stack Trace**

```
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:579)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:499)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:478)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:330)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:291)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:336)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:429)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:451)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:558)
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: Can you show the entire stack trace for the error?

Comment: @aru_sha4 edited the question with trace

Comment: execute this `mvn dependency:list` let me know if you got some transitive dependency.

Comment: If you use that dependency I would just declare it in the POM (instead of relying on transitive import).

Comment: @VishwaRatna I dont see that jar

Comment: is there any scope mentioned as `provided` or `test`??

Comment: @VishwaRatna No, there is no scope mentioned

Comment: @ghostrider , what you get after executing this?? `mvn clean package install`

Comment: @VishwaRatna, same error, package does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: The dependency is in the effective pom, but not in the dependencies section, but probably in the dependencyManagement section.

Anyway, if you need the dependency, just declare it in your pom.

Comment: The POM.xml is not editable for me. Also my doubt is why is it present in the Effective POM but not getting picked up while building

Comment: Are you really sure that the dependency in the effective pom is in the right section? Are you sure that it is not inside the `<dependencyManagement>` area?

Comment: It is inside the <dependencyManagement> tag. Do I have to explicitly import it in my POM?

Comment: dependencyManagement just defines standard version numbers. It does not add dependencies to the project. You need to add the dependency explicitly in your POM. You may leave out the version number, though.